# HDFS How to know from which host we get a file

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I use the command line and I want to know from which host I get a file (or which replica I get).

Normally it should be the nearest to me. But I changed a policy for the project. Thus I want to check the final results to see if my new policy works correctly.

Following command does not give any information:

> hadoop dfs -get /file

And the next one gives me only the replica's position, but not which one is preferred for the get:

> hadoop fsck /file -files -blocks -locations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks,

We finally use the networks statistics with a simple test case to find where hadoop takes the replicas.

But the easiest way is to print the array nodes modified by this method:

> org.apache.hadoop.net.NetworkTopology pseudoSortByDistance( Node reader, Node[] nodes )

As we expected, the get of the replicas is based on the results of the methods. The firsts items are preferred. Normally the first item is taken except if there is an error with the node. For more information about this method, see Replication

Answer (score 0):

HDFS abstracts this information away as it is not very useful for users to know where they are reading from (the filesystem is designed to be as less in your way as possible). Typically, the DFSClient intends to pick up the data in order of the hosts returned to it (moving onto an alternative in case of a failure). The hosts returned to it is sorted by the NameNode for appropriate data or rack locality - and that is how the default scenario works.

While the proper answer for your question would be to write good test cases that can both simulate and assert this, you can also run your program with the Hadoop logger set to DEBUG, to check the IPC connections made to various hosts (including DNs) when reading the files - and go through these to assert manually that your host-picking is working as intended.

Another way would be to run your client through a debugger and observe the parts around the connections made finally to retrieve data (i.e. after NN RPCs).